# Does the leaks tool in Instruments give false positives?

Tags: objective-c, instruments

I have autoreleased objects that I am assigning to synthesized (retain) properties on an object but it is marking them as leaked. Does leaks just sometimes have false positives or am I missing something?

Comment: Instruments has been known to give false positives, but what you describe is a legit leak. See below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a retain property will overrule an autorelease.

*EDIT* for clarity, I don't mean overrule. I mean... it will prevent an autorelease from forcing a dealloc. See comments for all the grimy details.

you should be manually releasing that property in your dealloc to let autorelease run its course

Comment: Or just set the property to nil like this: `self.MyProperty = nil` that will always release the item

Comment: Nitpicking, but there is no "overrule". The synthesized accessor for the retain property lays an *additional* ownership claim on the object, which then needs balancing by a corresponding release. (This may come from another call to the accessor, as @Richard suggests.) The autorelease, meanwhile, autoreleases as normal.

Comment: I was attempting to illustrate in laymen's terms. I'm not sure how helpful the complete technical overview would have been, given the nature of the question.

Comment: So if I have this
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *bar;
foo.bar = [NSMutableArray array];
I then have to release foo? I thought the property handled that.

Comment: [NSMutableArray array] is shorthand for [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease] -- which gives a retain count of 1, then the foo.bar assignment increases the retaincount to 2. autorelease will then reduce it back to 1, then foo.bar = nil to 0, garbage collect

Comment: but I thought the dealloc method automatically set properties to nil?

Comment: I"ve never heard of that but that doesn't mean it isn't true. Regardless, it's considered a good practice to make your intentions as a programmer very clear, so that other people know what you meant when you wrote it. No matter what, explicitly releasing it in dealloc will likely fix your Instruments leak.

Comment: I can't believe I've missed this for so long.